# How to move marker on gmsmapview in google sdk ios

Tags: ios

I want to move the marker on basis of lat,long which i'm getting continously I'm doing this like below...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations   (NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations 
{

CLLocationCoordinate2D coor2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(longitude, latitude);
    self.marker.position = coor2D;

}
```

The method is updating lat long but the markers is not moving why...
In info.plist I have added..
[image]

Comment: have you edit your plist file?

Comment: The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Are you just looking to update your current location?

Comment: YEs for now I only want to update my location...

Comment: I used kvo for that.  below is the sample code I used in my personal project.   Let me know if you need to see more or have anything clarified.   I won't have access to my personal pc til later tonight though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, assuming you have set your delegate:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations   (NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations 
{

CLLocationCoordinate2D coor2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(longitude, latitude);
    self.marker.position = coor2D;

[self.mapView animateToLocation:coord2D.coordinate]
}
```

If all you're trying to do is update your current location.  You should probably just use KVO for that.

```
@implementation MyLocationViewController {
  GMSMapView *mapView_;
  BOOL firstLocationUpdate_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.868
                                                          longitude:151.2086
                                                               zoom:12];

  mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
  mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
  mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

  // Listen to the myLocation property of GMSMapView.
  [mapView_ addObserver:self
             forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context:NULL];

  self.view = mapView_;

  // Ask for My Location data after the map has already been added to the UI.
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
  });
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [mapView_ removeObserver:self
                forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
                   context:NULL];
}

#pragma mark - KVO updates

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
  if (!firstLocationUpdate_) {
    // If the first location update has not yet been recieved, then jump to that
    // location.
    firstLocationUpdate_ = YES;
    CLLocation *location = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
    mapView_.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget:location.coordinate
                                                     zoom:14];
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: Yes I'm using KVO but for to update my current location(myLocation button).

Comment: valosip I have one more doubt can we talk on hangout give me ur email Id